# Increase the height of the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, height, cell

I have a UITableViewCell. Inside of the cell I have **UILabel** and **UIButton**, when user clicks the button the text expands but cell doesn't. So I want the cell to increase it's height with the label.

I have tried this code but it giving me a crash (unexpectedly found nil)

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .fade)
```

tried this one also, again crash

```
tableView.rowHeight = cellHeightNumber
```

So basically I want it to work like this

**Before expanding:**

[image: Before expanding]

**After expanding:**

[image: After expanding]

Comment: Turn on exception breakpoints in Xcode (see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode), and then you can figure out where your crash happens. That may help to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you post the actual crash log? This will help diagnose as to what's going wrong and will give some context as to the direction you should take.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy Nope

Comment: It crashes in **reloadRows** and says **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** @PratikPatel

Comment: Please share the code where that error occurs in your question.

Comment: First of all share your code work and storyboard constraints. Second, use UITableViewAutomaticDimension for row height. Third, use delegate method not property.

Comment: Reason of crash : you forcly unwrapping the Nil object. Check the line of crash, your object probably nil.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two solutions:

1. Ditch the `reloadRows` and use the `reloadData` instead, like so: `tableView.reloadData()`
2. Wrap your `reloadRows` between the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`, like so:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       tableView.beginUpdates()
       // Your reloadRows codes here
       tableView.endUpdates()
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

> UITableViewAutomaticDimension

provides a solution for displaying dynamic content.
Use below code in viewDidLoad:

> tableView.estimatedRowHeight = YourTableViewHeight tableView.rowHeight
>   = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Use this link :
http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Also set number of line 0 for label in table cell.

Hope it helps. :)